# bash script compile java

Tags: java, bash, shell, compilation

I need to write a bash script to compile my java program. I know it's a bit artificial but it is homework. (although I'm not sure the bash script is even marked, just used for the automated marking system)

I only have one java file `test.java` and the script is to only search its own directory: I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash          
javac test.java
```

and saved as `build.sh`, i tried to run this from the terminal as both `sh build.sh` and `bash build.sh` both gave me errors. Can anyone offer any help?

included errors:

```
build.sh: line 1: {rtf1ansiansicpg1252cocoartf1038cocoasubrtf350: command not found
build.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
build.sh: line 2: `{\fonttbl\f0\fmodern\fcharset0 Courier;\f1\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}'
```

Comment: what error? show the error message.

Comment: Did you `chmod u+x` it? If so, `./build.sh` should be enough.

Comment: We would need to know what the errors are. You should also make sure your bash script is executable by running: chmod +x build.sh
Could also be that javac isnt on your path. Check that the java compiler bin directory is on your path.

Comment: Are you sure it's test.java and not Test.java(Which is preferred coding standard).

Comment: I've added the permissions to make it executable. It's test.java, I know by convention it should be Test. but I'm only experimenting with the script right now. I ran the javac test.java from the terminal and it compiled fine and i was able to run it fine.

Comment: Did you write your bash script in TextEdit?  Try using a terminal editor such as emacs, vim, nano, or gedit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you've saved your script as rich text (RTF), not plain text.  Try re-saving it using your favourite plain-text-friendly editor?

Answer (score 3):

Silly question, but what editor did you use to edit your Java program?

It looks like your Java program is in RTF format and not plain ascii.

If you tell me you used Wordpad, I'm going to track you down, fly to your town, come to your work, and slap you silly. ***DO NOT EVER USE A NON-PROGRAM EDITOR FOR EDITING A PROGRAM***.

Sorry for the all capitalizations. I have a bunch of <strike>bozos</strike> <strike>cow-orkers</strike> *coworkers* at my work who think Wordpad and Notepad have been blessed by God himself as the perfect pair of program editors. At least once per week, I'm fixing problems caused by someone using these programs.

If you're on Windows, download [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). If you want to learn a **real** program editor, try [VIM](http://www.vim.org). If you're on Linux or Mac OS X, you already have VIM installed on your system. If you want a more GUI oriented program editor, try downloading [JEdit](http://www.jedit.org/).

Just make sure you use a true program editor the next time you need to edit a program -- even if it's nothing but a two line shell script.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the editor you're using adds some extra information to the file:

> {\fonttbl\f0\fmodern\fcharset0 Courier;\f1\fswiss\fcharset0
>   Helvetica;}'

what editor are you using? Try opening the file with something simple, like `nano`, and remove all the extra stuff.